# Why is my Animated Plotly Only showing one group?

Tags: r, plotly

In my animated Plotly, I'd like to see all 5 continents moving! as of right now it is only showing "Europe" which is also the color argument.

[image]

```
final_df<- rugby_data %>%
  group_by(continent, year) %>%
  summarize(age = mean(age))

final_df

###PLOT###

fig <- final_df %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~year,
    y = ~age, 
    size = ~age,      
    color = ~continent,
    frame = ~year,    
    text = ~age,
    hoverinfo = "text",
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'markers'  
  )

fig <- fig %>% layout(
    xaxis = list(
      type = "log"
    )
  )

fig
```

Comment: A key thing that would help us to answer this is if you could provide us the dataset. A common way to do that is ```dput()``` of the data, so ```dput(final_df)```.

Comment: You've obviously filtered or subset the data. Have you inspected what you expected? If you filtered the data for the year 1998, how many rows do you have?